# SciKit Learn R-squared is very different from square of Pearson's Correlation R

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pearson-correlation, scipy.stats, coefficient-of-determination

I have 2 numpy arrays ike so:

```
a = np.array([32.0, 25.97, 26.78, 35.85, 30.17, 29.87, 30.45, 31.93, 30.65, 35.49, 
              28.3, 35.24, 35.98, 38.84, 27.97, 26.98, 25.98, 34.53, 40.39, 36.3])

b = np.array([28.778585, 31.164268, 24.690865, 33.523693, 29.272448, 28.39742,
              28.950092, 29.701189, 29.179174, 30.94298 , 26.05434 , 31.793175,
              30.382706, 32.135723, 28.018875, 25.659306, 27.232124, 28.295502,
              33.081223, 30.312504])
```

When I calculate the R-squared using SciKit Learn I get a ***completely*** different value than when I calculate Pearson's Correlation and then square the result:

```
sk_r2 = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(a, b)
print('SciKit R2: {:0.5f}\n'.format(sk_r2))

pearson_r = scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, b)
print('Pearson R: ', pearson_r)
print('Pearson R squared: ', pearson_r[0]**2)
```

Results in:
SciKit R2: 0.15913

Pearson R:  (0.7617075766854164, 9.534162339384296e-05)
Pearson R squared:  0.5801984323799696

I realize that an R-squared value can sometimes be negative for a poorly fitting model (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative) and therefore the square of Pearson's correlation is not always equal to R-squared. However, I thought that for a positive R-squared value it was always equal to Pearson's correlation squared? How are these R-squared values so different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pearson correlation coefficient R and R-squared coefficient of determination are two completely different statistics.

You can take a look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

---

## update

Persons's r coefficient is a measure of linear correlation between two variables and is

[image]

where `bar x` and `bar y` are the means of the samples.

R2 coefficient of determination is a measure of goodness of fit and is

[image]

where `hat y` is the predicted value of `y` and `bar y` is the mean of the sample.

Thus

1. they measure different things
2. `r**2` is not equal to `R2` because their formula are totally different

---

## update 2

`r**2` is equal to `R2` only in the case that you calculate `r` with a variable (say `y`) and the predicted variable `hat y` from a linear model

Let's make an example using the two arrays you provided

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sps
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score as R2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([32.0, 25.97, 26.78, 35.85, 30.17, 29.87, 30.45, 31.93, 30.65, 35.49, 
              28.3, 35.24, 35.98, 38.84, 27.97, 26.98, 25.98, 34.53, 40.39, 36.3])

b = np.array([28.778585, 31.164268, 24.690865, 33.523693, 29.272448, 28.39742,
              28.950092, 29.701189, 29.179174, 30.94298 , 26.05434 , 31.793175,
              30.382706, 32.135723, 28.018875, 25.659306, 27.232124, 28.295502,
              33.081223, 30.312504])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': a,
    'y': b,
})

df.plot(x='x', y='y', marker='.', ls='none', legend=False);
```

[image]

now we fit a linear regression model

```
mod = sm.OLS.from_formula('y ~ x', data=df)
mod_fit = mod.fit()
print(mod_fit.summary())
```

output

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.580
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.557
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     24.88
Date:                Mon, 29 Mar 2021   Prob (F-statistic):           9.53e-05
Time:                        14:12:15   Log-Likelihood:                -36.562
No. Observations:                  20   AIC:                             77.12
Df Residuals:                      18   BIC:                             79.12
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     16.0814      2.689      5.979      0.000      10.431      21.732
x              0.4157      0.083      4.988      0.000       0.241       0.591
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        6.882   Durbin-Watson:                   3.001
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.032   Jarque-Bera (JB):                4.363
Skew:                           0.872   Prob(JB):                        0.113
Kurtosis:                       4.481   Cond. No.                         245.
==============================================================================
```

and compute both `r**2` and `R2` and we can see that in this case they're equal

```
predicted_y = mod_fit.predict(df.x)
print("R2 :", R2(df.y, predicted_y))
print("r^2:", sps.pearsonr(df.y, predicted_y)[0]**2)
```

output

```
R2 : 0.5801984323799696
r^2: 0.5801984323799696
```

You did `R2(df.x, df.y)` that can't be equal to our computed values because you used a measure of goodness-of-fit between independent `x` and dependent `y` variables. We instead used both `r` and `R2` with `y` and predicted value of `y`.

Comment: Please read the question properly. I am not comparing the Pearson correlation with R-squared directly. I am comparing the square of the Pearson correlation (pearson_r[0]**2) with the R-squared. For a positive R-square value, these should be equal.

Comment: I updated the answer with full explanation

Comment: This is simply not true. In the case of simple linear regression with only one predictor R2 = r2 = Corr(x,y)**2. See this link: https://economictheoryblog.com/2014/11/05/proof/

Comment: I explained more, hope that's clear now :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation too. For me it happened when I compared R-squared in scikit-learn with R-squared as it is calculated by R caret package.

The R-squared in R caret package, or in your case in `scipy.stats.pearsonr` is the square of "Pearson R" by the definition. A measure of correlation. See its definition [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)(by definition could be between zero and 1).

However, the R-squared in scikit-learn is a measure of accuracy, you can look at its definition in its [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score).(by definition could be between -Inf and 1).

Bottom line, don't compare them. They are different measures.

Comment: Please read the question properly. I am not comparing the Pearson correlation with R-squared directly. I am comparing the square of the Pearson correlation (pearson_r[0]**2) with the R-squared. For a positive R-square value, these should be equal.